# Check if URL is accessible by authenticated user

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I've setup a `spring-boot-1.5.3` application with `spring-security-4.2.2` and configured restricted paths based on authorities. The restrictions look similar to this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/accounts/**", "/roles/**")
                    .hasAuthority(ADMINISTRATOR)
                    .and()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                    .hasAuthority(USER)
                    .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

In short - I want users with authority `USER` to be able to access my entire web app except for `/accounts/**` and `/roles/**` paths. This configuration works fine and I get expected errors (403's) if I try to access these pages without having the appropriate authorities.

For users with `USER` authority, I would like to hide some URLs so that they don't make these requests and get `403` errors. **How can I check if a user is allowed to access a URL**?

So far I've tried injecting `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` and calling its `isAllowed` method, though that doesn't seem to work. For example:

```
// Helper class that returns authentication instance.
Authentication auth = AuthUtils.getAuthentication();

// Don't have permission to access /users, expect to get false result.
boolean res = webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed("/users", auth );

assert res == false; // fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to this problem by accessing internal filters of spring security (seems really hackish, though it works).

First I created a helper class to check if URLs are accessible:

```
public final class UrlAuthorization {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UrlAuthorization.class);

    private final FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;
    private final AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;

    public UrlAuthorization(FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource,
                            AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager) {

        this.securityMetadataSource = securityMetadataSource;
        this.accessDecisionManager = accessDecisionManager;
    }

    public boolean isAccessible(String url) {
        Authentication authentication = AuthUtils.getAuthentication();

        FilterInvocation invocation = new FilterInvocation(null, url, HttpMethod.GET.name());
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = securityMetadataSource
                .getAttributes(invocation);

        try {
            this.accessDecisionManager.decide(authentication, invocation, attributes);

        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            LOG.trace("Not allowed to access URL: {}", url, e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I added configuration to create a `Bean` for this class:

```
@Configuration
public class UrlAuthorizationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UrlAuthorization urlAuthorization(List<Filter> filters) {
        FilterSecurityInterceptor interceptor = getInterceptor(filters)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BeanCreationException("Could not get security interceptor"));

        return new UrlAuthorization(
                interceptor.getSecurityMetadataSource(),
                interceptor.getAccessDecisionManager()
        );
    }

    private Optional<FilterSecurityInterceptor> getInterceptor(List<Filter> filters) {
        for (Filter filter : filters) {
            if (filter instanceof FilterChainProxy) {
                for (SecurityFilterChain chain : ((FilterChainProxy) filter).getFilterChains()) {
                    for (Filter securityFilter : chain.getFilters()) {
                        if (securityFilter instanceof FilterSecurityInterceptor) {
                            return Optional.of(((FilterSecurityInterceptor) securityFilter));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

And finally, I can use it like this:

```
assert urlAuthorization.isAccessible("/accounts") == false;
assert urlAuthorization.isAccessible("/") == true;
```

Comment: great idea probably but does not work for @PreAuthorize. The FilterSecurityInterceptor I got does return securityMetaDataSource with "authenticated" filter only, while the URL in question has @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") annotation. Looks like I'd have to get different filter that will provide all conditions listed in PreAuthorize

Answer (score 0):

Instead use method to check whether the user has the authority.

```
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.isUserInRole(String role)
```

Comment: If I used this approach, I would have to perform this check before each URL (check if user has role before showing a specific URL). Also if I used this method, I would have to associate each URL with a specific role, while I have already done that in `WebSecurityConfig` via authorities. Also keep in mind that I'm not using roles, I'm using authorities. So this approach will not work for me.

Comment: Ideally, I want something like `WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(url)`. It should work I'm guessing, though it seems to always return `true` regardless of what arguments I provide to this method.